# Alternative for tikz's scope environment outside tikzpicture

Tags: tikz-pgf, scoping

I have a lot of small tikz graphics that I all want to scale down, so I'd like to put them in a scope, like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
    \begin{scope}[scale=0.3]
        \begin{tikzpicture}
%               Draw stuff in a small scale
        \end{tikzpicture}
        \begin{tikzpicture}
%               Draw more stuff in a small scale
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{scope}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
%           Draw stuff in normal scale again
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

But this doesn't work because the scope environment is only defined inside a tikzpicture.

How can I achieve this effect? Do I have to use `\tikzset` and save the current scale before scaling down and restoring it again at the end or is there a "proper" way of doing this?

Comment: If you want to make it smaller outside a `\tikzpicture` can use `\resizebox` command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `\tikzset{every picture/.style={scale=0.3}}` for this purpose. I enclose an example and a page preview of it where scaling is applied from 0.1 to 1.2 with a step of 0.1 to demonstrate its use.

```
%! *latex tikz-scaling-a.tex
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{tikz}
\parindent=0pt
\addtolength{\textheight}{1in}
\begin{document}
\def\malpicture{% Picture is changing, the font is not...
  \begin{tikzpicture}[x=1cm, y=1cm]
    \draw[line width=2pt, ](0,0)--(5,2);
    \node at (1,1) {Hello World!};
  \end{tikzpicture}
  }% End of \malpicture...
% A typical use... 
\malpicture\par
% And now with scaling...
\foreach\scaling in {0.1,0.2,...,1.2} {%
  \tikzset{every picture/.style={scale=\scaling}}% =0.3 etc.
  \fbox{\malpicture}\par
  }% End of \foreach\scaling...

\tikzset{every picture/.style={scale=0.3}}
\malpicture
\end{document}
```

[image: mwe]

I enclose one similar example where a TeX group (braces or `\begingroup` and `\endgroup`) is used to limit the `\tikzset` command. The first and the last pictures are without change, the second and the third one are affected by the `\tikzset` command.

```
%! *latex tikz-scaling-b.tex
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{tikz}
\parindent=0pt
\addtolength{\textheight}{1in}
\begin{document}

% A normal picture before a change is applied... 
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=1cm, y=1cm]
    \draw[line width=2pt, ](0,0)--(5,2);
    \node at (1,1) {Hello World!};
\end{tikzpicture}

% A group will limit the \tikzset command...
\begingroup % or we use opening brace "{"
\tikzset{every picture/.style={scale=0.3}} % a change in parameters
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=1cm, y=1cm]
    \draw[line width=2pt, ](0,0)--(5,2);
    \node at (1,1) {My first scaled picture!};
\end{tikzpicture}\par
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=1cm, y=1cm]
    \draw[line width=2pt, ](0,0)--(5,2);
    \node at (1,1) {My second scaled picture!};
\end{tikzpicture}%
\endgroup % or we use closing brace "}"

% A let's get back to normal scaling... 
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=1cm, y=1cm]
    \draw[line width=2pt, ](0,0)--(5,2);
    \node at (1,1) {My last picture!};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: mwe2]

Comment: Instead I could just do `\tikzset{scale=\scaling}` before every picture, right? My problem is that at the end of your loop, the scaling is still set at 1.2.

Comment: No need for it, use `\tikzset{every picture/.style={scale=0.3}}` when you need it (before the first picture and only once) and use `\tikzset{every picture/.style={scale=1.0}}` whenever you need a common scaling (after the last picture you wish to have scaled, again use it only once). You can alternatively put that first command within a TeX group (`{ }`), then only pictures within that group would be affected.

Comment: Yes, but if the scale before wasn't 1.0, this won't work. What is a group?

Comment: This command is a switcher, it is switching parameters until another change. If we want to limit a switcher, we put it in a group (`scope` is a term used by TikZ), e.g. `common scaling, starting a group: { \tikzset{every picture/.style={scale=0.3}} tikz pictures to be scaled } here is the end of group and common scaling again with another TikZ pictures`.

Comment: Of course, where were my braces? ;) Great, that works and is exactly what I meant! Do you want to post a new answer or modify your answer with that?

Comment: I am happy for you. I will add one more example to that post, no problem at all.